# Connecting to XMPP with SSL throws exception "error:100AE081:elliptic curve routines:EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name:unknown group"

Tags: php, python, linux, openssl, xmpp

I'm using xmpppy on a Fedora 19 computer for connecting to xmpp server which requires ssl connection.

Code:

```
client = xmpp.Client(self.domain, debug=[])
server = (self.server, 5222)
client.connect(server)
```

It was working fine, I didn't change anything in code. Then I installed some applications and updated Fedora, now it gives this error:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chat.py", line 20, in connect
    client.connect(server)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xmpp/client.py", line 205, in connect
    while not self.TLS.starttls and self.Process(1): pass
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xmpp/dispatcher.py", line 303, in dispatch
    handler['func'](session,stanza)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xmpp/transports.py", line 337, in StartTLSHandler
    self._startSSL()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xmpp/transports.py", line 315, in _startSSL
    tcpsock._sslObj    = socket.ssl(tcpsock._sock, None, None)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 64, in ssl
    return _realssl.sslwrap_simple(sock, keyfile, certfile)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 477, in sslwrap_simple
    ssl_sock.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:100AE081:elliptic curve routines:EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name:unknown group
```

I also tried to connect to XMPP server using PHP

```
 $this->send_xml($this->START_TLS);
 $xml = $this->recv_xml();
 stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->fp, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
```

but it throws

```
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:100AE081:elliptic curve routines:EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name:unknown group
error:1408D010:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_KEY_EXCHANGE:EC lib in /var/www/html/libs/xmpp.php on line 71
```

Comment: Problem fixed by install openssl 26 Oct update

Comment: I have latest version and still got problems

Comment: I too was seeing this on CentOS until I updated the openssl package. Then it went away.